# Extract Time and IP addresses from router log file

Tags: logging, sed, router, extract

I have a DD-WRT router which is forwarding log files to GNOME's system log viewer and it works well. The problem I have is the router is sending far more information that I would like to keep track of:

```
Sep  9 20:41:17 192.168.1.1 kernel: [  272.160000] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=ppp0 MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=64.233.160.0 LEN=104 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=31811 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=42633 DPT=3000 LEN=84
```

How can I reduce this down to just the `Date`, `time`, `ACCEPT`, `SRC=IP` and `DST=IP`?

`ACCEPT` could also be `DROP` or `REJECT`.

As an experiment I tried:

```
sed 's/.*SRC=\([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/' -e 's/.*DST=\([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/' myrouter.log
```

All it did was create a long list of `SRC IP`'s and then a long list if `DST IP`'s. I was ideally hoping to get them on the same line for the log viewer.

Comment: long list of SRC than DST is in fact line where SRC is present (an no other info from this line) and list of line where SRC is NOT present but DST well because you ask sed to change line have SRC to only SRC+IP and just after to change the new content (so not changed if not SRC inside) to keep ONLY DST+IP info.

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$8,$12,$13}' myrouter.log
Sep 9 20:41:17 ACCEPT SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=64.233.160.0
```

---

Remove the labels:

```
awk '{split($12,a,"=");split($13,b,"=");print $1,$2,$3,$8,a[2],b[2]}' myrouter.log
Sep 9 20:41:17 ACCEPT 192.168.1.5 64.233.160.0
```

Comment: Perfect output and is exactly what I was looking for. awk works much better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/^\([a-zA-Z0-9 ]\{6,7\}[0-9:]\{8\} \).* \([ACCEPTDROPJ] \).*\(\([SRCDT]\{3\}=[0-9.]\{7,15\} *\)\{2\}\).*/\1\2\3/p'  YourFile
```

use the -n to filter line that does not correspond to this structure. Rest is pure pattern matching and group

If info are always at same place, other tools (AWK specially) are faster and easier to use in this case